# Implementing Search Form with Django

Tags: python, django

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am having trouble with my form not rendering in Django.

[image: Where the form is suppose to be]

Here's my attempt to render an empty form in `views.py`.

```py
class SearchSite(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(label="New Item",
     help_text="Search for any article located on the site.")
    
def search(request):

    form = SearchSite()        
   
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "query_matches": query_matches
    }

    response = render(request, "encyclopedia/layout.html", context)
    return response
```

Here's what my `urls.py` file looks like:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:page_title>", views.page, name="wiki"),
    path("wiki/", views.search, name="site_search") 
]
```

My `layout.html` file:

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                
                <form action="{% url 'site_search' %}" method="get">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    There should be something here
                    {{ form }}
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>

                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Create New Page
                </div>
                <div>
                    Random Page
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have noticed two particular problems in above screenshot. Firstly, my form does not render when inside my `index.html` webpage, which extends `layout.html`. Secondly, when I click the submit button, I get routed to a webpage that has my CSRF token in the url ... and then finally renders my form.

How can I fix this? Thanks everyone.

[image: Where I get linked Instead]

Comment: I think this has something to do with / route calling the views.index function and not the views.search function, so it's never going to show the form on the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have noticed two particular problems in above screenshot. Firstly,
> my form does not render when inside my `index.html` webpage, which
> extends `layout.html`.

Yes. You aren't passing `form` to `index.html`. Pass that in the view which renders the homepage. Even if it extends from `layout.html`, you need to pass it in the context for it to work.

```py
def index(request):
    # Your code.
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': SearchSite()})
```

> Secondly, when I click the submit button, I get routed to a webpage
> that has my CSRF token in the url ... and then finally renders my
> form.

That's because, in `index.html`, there is a blank form with a `csrf_token`, with an action set to `/wiki`, which calls `search` when the submit button is pressed. And `search` gives you `layout.html`, with the form, and as the form method is `GET`, it shows it in the url. I suggest changing it to `POST` if there is confidential data (and even otherwise. Why is there a `csrf_token` if it is not a POST request? Not needed. If you really want a GET request, then remove the `csrf_token`).

Comment: Thank you. That was a silly mistake to have the csrf_token. So to clarify, if I am planning on using my search to redirect me to a search page, I should be using get, as there is no confidential data? The get request is always putting query=SEARCHITEM in the url, how do I avoid that?

Comment: Use post and keep the csrf_token. For forms, mostly use post, because it's annoying to see long urls, and get requests put the data in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to the problem I had earlier for any future people visiting the post.

I wrote a form called `SearchSite` and defined a view called `search` in my `views.py`.

```py
class SearchSite(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(
     help_text="Search for any article located on the site.")
    
def search(request):

    form = SearchSite()
    is_substring_of_queries = []
        
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = SearchSite(request.GET)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            for entry in util.list_entries():
                existsIdenticalResult = form.cleaned_data["query"].casefold() == entry.casefold() 
                existsResult = form.cleaned_data["query"].casefold() in entry.casefold()    
                if existsIdenticalResult:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("wiki",
                     kwargs={"page_title": entry}))
                elif existsResult: 
                    is_substring_of_queries.append(entry)
        
    context = {
        "form": SearchSite(),
        "is_substring_of_queries": is_substring_of_queries
    }

    response = render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", context)
    return response
```

When my `view.search` is requested, it will send the response of either an empty form (if accessed by `index.html` or if there are no results with a message saying there are no results) , an empty form and all the queries that are substrings of the markdown entries or route the client to an exact entry if the query matched.

Here's the routing down in my `urls.py` so far:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:page_title>", views.page, name="wiki"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="site_search")
]
```

In my `layout.html`, I have the following form:

```html
<form action="{% url 'site_search' %}" method="get">
    {{ form }}                
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

as well as in my search.html the queries that are substrings of the markdown entries:

```html
{% if is_substring_of_queries %}
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
            {% for query in is_substring_of_queries%}
                <li><a href="{% url 'wiki' query %}"> {{ query }} </a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}

        <h1>No Results! Try again.</h1>
        {% endif %}
```

If there are any mistakes, please let me know.